# MySQL not using optimum composite key

Tags: mysql, database, performance, indexing

I have a table which I've added a couple of composite keys to:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_foo on my_table(col_one, col_two, col_three);

CREATE INDEX idx_bar on my_table(col_one, col_four, col_three);
```

Why, when I use `EXPLAIN` on the following query, does MySQL tell me it's using the less-appropriate `idx_bar` key?

```
SELECT col_one, col_two, col_three, col_four FROM my_table
WHERE col_one = 'a'
AND col_two = 1
AND col_three = 1
```

returns:

```
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'my_table','ref','IDX_E93438563DAE168B,idx_foo,idx_bar','idx_bar','767','const','6688','Using index condition; Using where'
```

Am I overestimating MySQL's matching engine, or have I made a mistake? Is the only solution to use `FORCE INDEX`?

Comment: what does the table look like and what is the cardinality of the tables???

Comment: Indeed silly. One of the composite keys is clearly 'better' as it is a full cover of the criteria (with both composites initially covering the same column and diverging immediately after), independent of any cardinality involved. (I would be less surprised/intrigued if it chose a different non-composite index or scan.) Can you include the EXPLAIN output?

Comment: Also, do make sure that *both* indices have up-to-date statistics.

Comment: @user2864740 Really? My `idx_foo` matches the WHERE portion of my statement exactly, so I assumed MySQL would choose that. I've included the explain output if that helps.

Comment: @Jonathan I agree that it *should* select the foo_idx column because it is trivially 'better'. It would be interesting to see all the different weights MySQL takes into account for the selection (could it be biased by index row size? index overall size? is the cardinality estimation different and in favor of the non-condition-covering index? is cache heat considered?) - this level of details is unknown to me.

Comment: Let's see the actual `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the actual `SELECT`.  I think were are missing something subtle.

Answer (score 1):

Wait!  You say that `col_one` is UNIQUE?  Then *any* index *starting* with `col_one` will find the answer in *one* try!

So, here's why it picked the 'wrong' index:  It is smaller.

Comment: (Did the OP say that?)

Comment: I was sure I saw it in a comment from OP, but I don't see it now ???  Was it deleted?  The `SHOW CREATE TABLE` was provide confirmation.  My Answer is the _could_ explain the conflicting observations.

Comment: I've no doubt that it could be the cause .. but I didn't / don't currently see such information from the OP. More details would indeed be relevant.